# CSV file structure for a java object

Tags: java, csv

I want a CSV format for `Order` objects. My `Order` Object will have order `details`, `order line details` and `item details`. Please find the java object below:

```
Order {
    OrderNo, OrderName, Price,
    OrderLine {
              OrderLineNo, OrderLinePrice,
             Item{
                  ItemNo, ItemName, Item Description
             }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please guide me to create csv format for this.

Comment: How about these columns: OrderNo, OrderName, Price, OrderLineNo, OrderLinePrice, ItemNo, ItemName, ItemDescription? Or am I missing anything?

Comment: You are right, but what if there are multiple OrderLines and Items?

Comment: You will need to duplicate a lot of data if you want a simple flat structure.

Comment: Just assign an ID to each Order and use multiple lines to define the order's content. As @PM77-1 stated this will produce a lot of duplicate data

Answer (score 0):

Have a POJO class for your Object for which you want to create CSV file and use java.io.FileWriter to write/append values in csv file. This [Java-code-geek Link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/writeread-csv-files-in-java-example/) will help you with this.

Comment: Not very helpful.  In the sample the class has only primitives as class variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are feeling adventurous, I'm building support for nested elements in CSV in [uniVocity-parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers).

The 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT version supports parsing nested beans with annotations. We are planning to release the final version in a couple of weeks. Writing support has not been implemented yet, so that part you'll have to do manually (should be fairly easy with the current API).

Parsing this sort of structure is more complex, but the parser seems to be working fine for most cases. Have a look at that test case:

**Input CSV:**

```
1,Foo
Account,23234,HSBC,123433-000,HSBCAUS
Account,11234,HSBC,222343-130,HSBCCAD
2,BAR
Account,1234,CITI,213343-130,CITICAD
```

Note that the first column of each row identifies which bean will be read. As "Client" in the CSV matches the class name, you don't need to annotate

**Pojos**

```
enum ClientType {
    PERSONAL(2),
    BUSINESS(1);

    int typeCode;

    ClientType(int typeCode) {
        this.typeCode = typeCode;
    }
}

public static class Client {
    @EnumOptions(customElement = "typeCode", selectors = { EnumSelector.CUSTOM_FIELD })
    @Parsed(index = 0)
    private ClientType type;

    @Parsed(index = 1)
    private String name;

    @Nested(identityValue = "Account", identityIndex = 0, instanceOf = ArrayList.class, componentType = ClientAccount.class)
    private List<ClientAccount> accounts;
}

public static class ClientAccount {
    @Parsed(index = 1)
    private BigDecimal balance;
    @Parsed(index = 2)
    private String bank;
    @Parsed(index = 3)
    private String number;
    @Parsed(index = 4)
    private String swift;
}
```

**Code to parse the input**

```
public void parseCsvToBeanWithList() {
    final BeanListProcessor<Client> clientProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<Client>(Client.class);

    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
    settings.setRowProcessor(clientProcessor);

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    parser.parse(new StringReader(CSV_INPUT));

    List<Client> rows = clientProcessor.getBeans();
}
```

If you find any issue using the parser, please send update [this issue](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/issues/13)